# Do all Solid State Relays function as diodes?

Tags: solid-state-relay

I just installed a solid state relay as the main power switch for a robot I'm working on.  The robot is controlled by a Windows 8 tablet and I thought it would be cool to use the tablet to turn the bot on and off.  Not long after I started using the relay I realized that the battery wasn't charging (the charger was installed after the relay).  Once I connected the charger directly to the battery it started charging - this means that the relay was acting as a large diode.  Is this an effect of all Solid State Relays?  If so, this could be a very large problem for some applications.

Comment: No. There are many kinds of SSR. Datasheet? Schematic?

Answer (score 5):

Some SSRs do work like that, some don't.  If the output leads are marked with a polarity, then it matters.  There are "AC" SSRs that are two back to back light-activated SCRs.  In that case the polarity doesn't matter.

One issue with SSRs is that they can have significant voltage drops, from a few 100 mV to over a volt.  You don't want that between the charger and the battery anyway.  Even if this were a mechanical relay, you still wouldn't want it between the charger and the battery.  You'd then only be able to charge when the unit is on, which makes little sense.